# how to play all video formats in html 5?

Tags: html, video

Here i have one demo.jsp where i'm uploading videos to folder and i'm playing those videos using html5.but the problem is when i specified /mp4 or ogg then such type only playing if i'm uploading different format type example .mp4,.avg.,.fly.ogg then how can i give such all formats

observe this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_bear  ,here they specified format type.Rather than this type="video/mp4" is there any alternate way which support all formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that not all browsers support all formats. That's the major problem with the new `video` tag in HTML5. There was a major discussion going on between the closed-source vendors and open-source vendors, and they decided that they would allow multiple formats, and that everyone supports what they want to.

So as an answer: **no**, there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries like [MediaElementJS](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/), [JPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), [JWPlayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/),..
They try html to play the media and as a fallback use flash with similar view.

I recommend using mediaelementjs.

hope helps.